# How to go up a level in the src path of a URL in HTML?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I am storing style sheets in {root}/styles while images in {root}/images for a website. 
How do I give the path in the style sheets to go look in the images directory for the specified images?

e.g. In `background-image: url('/images/bg.png');`

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Use `..` to indicate the parent directory:

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
```

Comment: I read that elsewhere as well- but it doesn't work! (at least in Chrome)

Comment: It does. However note that the location is relative to the CSS file's location, not the document embedding the CSS file.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It should be if we're using only inline CSS

Answer (score 98):

**Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:**

- **Starting with** `/` returns to the root directory and starts there
- **Starting with** `../` moves one directory backward and starts there
- **Starting with** `../../` moves two directories backward and starts there (and so on...)
- **To move forward**, just start with the first sub directory and keep moving forward.

Click [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) for more details!

Answer (score 53):

Use `../`:

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
```

You can use that as often as you want, e.g. `../../images/` or even at different positions, e.g. `../images/../images/../images/` (same as `../images/` of course)

Answer (score 10):

In Chrome when you load a website from some HTTP server both absolute paths (e.g. `/images/sth.png`) and relative paths to some upper level directory (e.g. `../images/sth.png`) work.

**But!**

When you load (in Chrome!) a HTML document from local filesystem you cannot access directories above current directory. I.e. you cannot access `../something/something.sth` and changing relative path to absolute or anything else won't help.

Comment: Upon rechecking, I can report that the local file system relative-paths by using `../` do work fine - or at least does work fine in this specific case!

Comment: It does work on linux and windows, not on mac (my experience)

Comment: Links do not count here, as there is no same origin check for them. Also this answer is 6 years old so browsers may have changed a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you store stylesheets/images in a folder so that multiple websites can use them, or you want to re-use the same files on another site on the same server, I have found that my browser/Apache does not allow me to go to any parent folder above the website root URL. This seems obvious for security reasons - one should not be able to browse around on the server any place other than the specified web folders.

Eg. does not work: www.mywebsite.com/../images

As a workaround, I use Symlinks:

Go to the directory of www.mywebsite.com
Run the command ln -s ../images images

Now www.mywebsite.com/images will point to www.mywebsite.com/../images

Comment: what is symlinks?

Comment: "A symlink (also called a symbolic link) is a type of file in Linux that points to another file or a folder on your computer. Symlinks are similar to shortcuts in Windows. Some people call symlinks "soft links" – a type of link in Linux/UNIX systems – as opposed to "hard links." " ------ from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/symlink-tutorial-in-linux-how-to-create-and-remove-a-symbolic-link/

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the following file structure:

```
-css
  --index.css
-images
  --image1.png
  --image2.png
  --image3.png
```

In CSS you can access `image1`, for example, using the line `../images/image1.png`.

**NOTE**: If you are using Chrome, it may doesn't work and you will get an error that the file could not be found. I had the same problem, so I just **deleted the entire cache history from chrome** and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to go to the root of the  folder use   / or ctrl+space
if you want to go to the back folder use   ../  and ctrl+space if it dont suggest
and not use the live server if you use the  ../