# CSS text isn't correct, image adress won't work

Tags: html, css, image, text, background

How do I write the right adress, the code is:

```
.slide1 {  
    background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
}
```

How do I put a image from my resource file? I tried `background-image: url("pic1.jpg")` -that's the right address- and it doesn't work.

What I do is I put the images from a slideshow in css and put a simple cod afterwards in html to display it.

Comment: If you are pulling the image from a directory/folder that is outside of your .html file structure, then you have to specify the path to that (ex: url(images/pic1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a `width` and a `height` in order to make it appear. Try it like this:

```
.slide1 {  
    background: url('http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg') no-repeat center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Edit:**
If the image is in the same directory where your css file is, simply use:

```
background: url('nameOftheFile.jpg') no-repeat center;
```

Also this thread may be interesting for you: [How to go up a level in the src path of a URL in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810927/how-to-go-up-a-level-in-the-src-path-of-a-url-in-html)

Comment: I did this, as: .slider {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;

Comment: my question is how do I write the path to a img file on my resource file, not like in the example I found, online image. Thanks!

Comment: @danut is the image file in the same directory as your css?

Comment: No, it is in the "website" directory, where the index and all the other pages are, in HTML format. I used images from there on other page than index, and the others pics i use are in assets/img/..

Comment: I'll just put them there, thanks for the help, now I saw the edit. Thanks again!

Comment: @danut you're welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as solved if it helped you.