# Correct way to set a background image path for development and production?

Tags: css, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I simply want to give my `html` a CSS background image.

I tried setting it to this:

```
html {background-image: url('/assets/background.jpg')}
```

which worked on development, but then when assets are compiled into the `Public` folder, it's no longer the correct path. This:

```
html {background-image: url('background.jpg')}
```

doesn't even work on development.

I'm pretty confused because nobody seems to have had this same problem, but it seems like it should be a pretty common one.

Any light shed would be much appreciated.

Comment: use full path of image from the starting folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your folder structure is like

```
/css
/js
/img
```

In most cases css and images will be in their separate folders so you need to go back one step by using `../` It means it will go back one folder so the correct CSS property would be,

```
html {background-image: url('../img/background.jpg')}
```

**This will work in all situation and servers unless you chnage the folder structure.**

And if your css and images both are in same folder you can just write

```
html {background-image: url('background.jpg')}
```

for more information see this thread : [How to go up a level in the src path of a URL in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810927/how-to-go-up-a-level-in-the-src-path-of-a-url-in-html)

CSS- tricks blog - [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)