# i want to link one page which is inside the folder to another page which is outside the folder

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNld4.jpg)

I really need your help here because this is confusing me now. i am in the customesignup.php inside the customer folder. Now i want to link this page to index.php which is outside the customer folder. And that page of index.php is not in any folder it is just hanging outside of the customer folder as you can see in the above picture. help please. .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go up a level in the src path of a URL in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810927/how-to-go-up-a-level-in-the-src-path-of-a-url-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="../index.php>linktext</a>` as relative path or as absolute path if this is web root folder `<a href="/index.php>linktext</a>`

Answer (score -1):

../ will bring you out of the folder costom ant thn wrtie your file name