# Link as an image doesn't work but works on a text

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

My code is simple and basic however it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

The link works great with text though. The cursor doesn't change, it stays as an arrow.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="link"><img id= "pil" src="myimage.jpg" alt="pil"></a>
    <a href="link"><img id= "yoyo" src="myimage2.jpg" alt="yoyo"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS : main {
                             text-align:center;
                             display: inline-block;
                               }

                          #pil {
                               max-width: 300px;
                               max-height: 200px;
                               margin: 0px;
                               }
        
                            #yoyo {
                               width: 300px;
                               height: 200px;
                               margin: 0px;
                               }

Comment: Almost certainly a path issue

Answer (score 1):

[Look carefully at the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrYMS.png)

It seems that you did't use the correct path.  [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810927/how-to-go-up-a-level-in-the-src-path-of-a-url-in-html)

Comment: Thank you Dima for your answer, The image charge just fine and the link works perfectly when I replace the image with a text so I am not sure wich link you are thinking about? the image ?

Comment: @Algocph Sorry, I wanted to mention the **path**